# How can I evaluate existential quantifiers in the set theory?

Tags: quantifiers

I can't understand why the following conversions are possible.

- A = {x ∈ N : ∃n ∈ N(x = 2n)}  ⋯ ①
- = {x ∈ N : x is even} ⋯ ②

A is the set of all x is in the natural numbers, such that there is at least one natural number n such that x = 2n. In other words, there is at least n such that x is even. But ② statement means that all x is even.

So, I don't understand why the ③ is wrong, which used universal quantifiers.

- A = {x ∈ N : ∀n ∈ ( = 2) } ⋯ ③

Below is the Textbook Citation.

> A = {x ∈ N : ∃n ∈ N(x = 2n)}
>
> Let’s look at this carefully. First, there are some new symbols to
> digest: “N” is the symbol usually used to denote that natural numbers,
> which we will take to be the set {0, 1, 2, 3, . . .}. Next, the colon,
> “:”, is read such that; it separates the elements that are in the set
> from the condition that the elements in the set must satisfy. So
> putting this all together, we would read the set as, “the set of all x
> in the natural numbers, such that there exists some n in the natural
> numbers for which x is twice n.” In other words, the set of all
> natural numbers, that are even. Here is another way to write the same
> set.
>
> A = {x ∈ N : x is even}.

Comment: The definition of “$x$ is even” is $\exists n \in N (x = 2n)$. This is why $\{x \in N \mid \exists n \in N (x = 2n)\} = \{x \in N \mid x \text{ is even}\}$.

Comment: I don't understand why the following is wrong, which used universal quantifiers instead of existential quantifiers.

A = {x ∈ N : ∀n ∈ ( = 2) }

Comment: @Aspas Can you name a natural number $x$ such that $\forall n\in\Bbb N(x=2n)$ ?

Comment: @ Sassatelli Giulio
Thank you. I made the mistake of thinking about the condition of n instead of x.